# Header file not found cpp

Tags: c++

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
//#include "cfgtocnf.h"
#include "cyk.h"
using namespace std;



    int main(){
        int option;
        cout << "Select an option below: \n";
        cout << "1. CFG to CNF \n";
        cout << "2. CYK \n";
        cin >> option;

        switch(option){
            case 1:
                //output();
                break;
            case 2:
                cykoutput();
                break;

        }
    }
```

cyk.h

```
#ifndef CYK_H
#define CYK_H

// This is the content of the .h file, which is where the declarations go
void cykoutput(); 

// This is the end of the header guard
#endif
```

cyk.cpp

```
//CNF grammer to CYK Chart
//statement to infom user whether the string can/cannot be generated by the grammar

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "cyk.h"

using namespace std;

string grammer[50][50];

bool state_checking1( string a){
    if ( a.length() == 1 && (a[0] >= 'A' && a[0] <='Z') ) {
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}

bool input_checking(string a){
    if (a.length() == 1 && (a[0] >= 'a' && a[0] <= 'z')) {
        return true;
    }
    else if (a.length() == 2 && (a[0] >= 'A' && a[0] <= 'Z' && a[1] >= 'A' && a[1] <= 'Z')){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}

bool remove_line1(int line , string a){
    bool end = false;
    bool check_grammer = true;
    size_t line_position = -1;
    int y = 1 , start = 0;

    while (!end && check_grammer){
        line_position = a.find("|");
        if (line_position != -1){
            a.erase(line_position,1);
            line_position = line_position - start;
            grammer[line][y] = a.substr(start, line_position);
            check_grammer = input_checking(grammer[line][y]);
            if (check_grammer == false){
                break;
            }
            y++;
            start = start + line_position;
        }
        else{
            end = true;
            grammer[line][y] = a.substr(start, line_position);
            check_grammer = input_checking(grammer[line][y]);
        }
    }

    return check_grammer;
}

string search(string a, int grammer_line_count){
    string temp = "";
    int k;
    for (int j = 0; j < grammer_line_count; j++){
        k = 1;
        while (grammer[j][k] != "")
        {
            if (grammer[j][k] == a)
            {
                temp += grammer[j][0];
            }
            k++;
        }
    }

    return temp;
}

string compare(string a, string b, int grammer_line_count){
    string temp ,temp2 = "";
    string aa = a;
    string bb = b;

    if (aa.find("_") ==0){
        aa = aa.substr(1, aa.length());
    }

    if (bb.find("_") == 0){
        bb = bb.substr(1, bb.length());
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < aa.length();  i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < bb.length(); j++){
            temp = "";
            temp = temp + aa[i] + bb[j];
            temp2 = temp2 + search(temp, grammer_line_count);
        }
    }

    return temp2;
}

void cykoutput(){
    ifstream file;
    string file_name , file_line , input_string;
    size_t search_pointer;
    bool done = false;
    bool isGrammer;
    string check_generated;

    //to output to file
    ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open ("cyk.txt");


    while (!done) {
        int grammer_line_count = 0;
        isGrammer = true;
        cout<<"=============================================================================="<<endl;
        cout<<"\t\tCNF Grammar to CYK Chart Generator\n";
        cout<<"==============================================================================\n"<<endl;
        cout<<"**Enter -1 to exit**\nPlease enter CNF Grammar file name (e.g. xxx.txt) : ";
        cin>>file_name;

        if (file_name != "-1"){
            file.open(file_name.c_str());
            if (file) {
                cout << "\nCNF Grammer : \n" << endl;
                for (int i = 0; getline(file, file_line); i++) {
                    cout << file_line << endl;
                    search_pointer = file_line.find("->");
                    if (i == 0){
                        check_generated = file_line.substr(0, search_pointer);
                    }

                    grammer[i][0] = file_line.substr(0, search_pointer);
                    grammer_line_count++;
                    if (isGrammer) {
                        isGrammer = state_checking1(grammer[i][0]);
                        file_line = file_line.substr(search_pointer + 2, file_line.length());
                        isGrammer = remove_line1(i, file_line);
                    }
                }

                file.close();

                if (!isGrammer) {
                    cout << "\nInvalid grammar!!!" << endl;
                }
                else{
                    cout << "\nEnter the input string : ";
                    cin >> input_string;

                    //Assign value-----------------
                    string temp;
                    string temp2;
                    string cykTable[50][50];


                    int input_length = input_string.length();
                    for (int i = 0; i < input_length; i++){
                        int y = 0;
                        temp = "";
                        temp2 = "";
                        temp+= input_string[i];

                        temp2 = search(temp, grammer_line_count);
                        cykTable[i][y] = temp2;
                    }

                    //compare the value------------
                    int x,y;
                    for (int i = 1; i < input_length; i++){ //already write 1st 1ine need to +1
                        y = i - 1;
                        x = 0;
                        for (int j = 0; j < (input_length - i); j++){
                            if (cykTable[x][y] != "DONE"){
                                if (cykTable[x][y + 1] == ""){
                                    if (cykTable[x + 1][y] != "DONE"){
                                        temp = "";
                                        temp = compare(cykTable[x][y], cykTable[x + 1][y], grammer_line_count);
                                        if (temp != ""){
                                            cykTable[x + 1][y + 1] = "DONE";
                                        }
                                        else{
                                            if (cykTable[x][y].find("_") == 0){
                                                temp = cykTable[x][y];
                                            }
                                            else{
                                                temp = "_" + cykTable[x][y];
                                            }
                                        }

                                        cykTable[x][y + 1] = temp;
                                    }
                                    else{
                                        int xx = x;
                                        while (cykTable[xx + 1][y] == "DONE"){
                                            xx++;
                                        }
                                        temp = "";
                                        temp = compare(cykTable[x][y], cykTable[xx + 1][y], grammer_line_count);
                                        if (temp != ""){
                                            cykTable[xx + 1][y + 1] = "DONE";
                                        }
                                        else{
                                            if (cykTable[x][y].find("_") == 0){
                                                temp = cykTable[x][y];
                                            }
                                            else{
                                                temp = "_" + cykTable[x][y];
                                            }
                                        }

                                        cykTable[x][y + 1] = temp;
                                    }
                                }

                            }
                            x++;
                        }

                        for (int k = 0; k < input_length; k++){
                            if (cykTable[k][i] == ""){
                                if (cykTable[k][i - 1] != "DONE"){
                                    if (cykTable[k][i-1].find("_") == 0){
                                        cykTable[k][i] = cykTable[k][i - 1];
                                    }
                                    else{
                                        cykTable[k][i] = "_" + cykTable[k][i-1];
                                    }

                                }
                                else{
                                    cykTable[k][i] = "DONE";
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    //print out the cyk table------
                    myfile << "\n=========================================================" << endl;
                    myfile << "\t\tCYK Chart\n";
                    myfile << "=========================================================\n" << endl;

                    string check123;
                    y = 0;
                    for (int i = 0; i < input_length; i++){
                        if (i == input_length - 1){
                            if (cykTable[0][y].find("_") != -1){
                                search_pointer = cykTable[0][y].find("_");
                                cykTable[0][y] = cykTable[0][y].substr(search_pointer + 1, cykTable[0][y].length());
                            }
                            myfile<< cykTable[0][y];
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            for (int j = 0; j < input_length - i; j++){
                                check123 = "";

                                if (cykTable[j][y] == "DONE" || (cykTable[j][y].find("_") == 0)){
                                    check123 = "";
                                }
                                else{
                                    check123 = cykTable[j][y];
                                }

                                myfile << check123 << "\t";
                            }
                        }

                        y++;
                        myfile << endl;

                    }

                    //check either can be generated

                    int test = cykTable[0][input_length - 1].find(check_generated);
                    if ( test >= 0){
                        myfile << "\nString can be generated!!!\n"<<endl;
                    }
                    else{
                        myfile << "\nString can not be generated!!!\n"<<endl;
                    }

                } //end else

            }
            else {
                cout << "\nFile Not Found!!!" << endl;
            }

            system("PAUSE");
            system("CLS");

            for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++){
                for (int j = 0; j < 50; j++){
                    grammer[i][j] = "";
                }
            }
        }
        else{
            done = true;
        }
    }


}
```

When I tried to compile, it shows

```
fatal error: cyk.h: no such file or directory:
```

What's wrong here ? I am using codeblocks and all the files are under one project. I have already created the cyk.h under Header section but it says no such file or directory.

Comment: Is it in the same directory as the `cpp` files?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not related to your source code per se, please check your compiler settings: note that source code and headers directories are set separately (although they might point to the same directory)

Answer (score 0):

please check the header file search path configuration in Build Options of codeblocks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a shortcut solution:
Open Code::Blocks, open "Settings" menu, click "Compiler...". Open the "Build Options" tab, and check the option "Explicitly add the current compiling file's directory...".[image]

If not, you should configure your Compiler settings. If you don't know, then try crazy and learn. It's in "Search Directories" tab under "Global Compiler Settings".